# Why am I not getting the output when I use Strcmp?

Tags: c

**when I use `strcmp`:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *i, *j;
    
    scanf("%s %s", &i, &j);
    
    if (strcmp(i, j) == 0){
        printf("Same \n");
    } else {
        printf("different\n");
    }
}
```

output: gives no output just blank

**When I directly compare i & j**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *i, *j;
    
    scanf("%s %s", &i, &j);
    
    if (i == j) {
        printf("Same \n");
    } else {
        printf("different\n");
    }
}
```

output : `Same`

Ye that's all I tried by replacing `i == j` with `strcmp()`.

Comment: Where are the buffers? Two pointers do not two buffers make... The problem is not in your `strcmp()`, really.... It's in your definition of `i` and `j`... (PS: The names `i` and `j` do NOT suggest that they are in someway connected to "strings"... Just a thought._

Comment: @starboy_jb "reading the string properly"... First: there are TWO strings (kinda) involved. Second: Passing the address of a pointer (or, when corrected the address of the name of an array (double indirection)) is NOT proper... Third: There is no evidence of any code checking the return code from `scanf()`... Not a good response...

Comment: Enable warnings for you compiler and pay attention to them.  Something like `-Wall -Werror` with gcc or clang will show you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to the use of `strcmp`, you have undefined behavior in the way you use `scanf()` to read strings.  You pass the addresses of string pointers where `scanf()` expects addresses of `char` arrays.

In both cases, the behavior is undefined and indeed the first program causes a segmentation fault, whereas the second seems to produce expected behavior, only by chance because the entered strings are short. Try longer strings and you might get a segmentation fault as well.

Here is a modified version with defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char i[100], j[100];
    
    if (scanf("%99s %99s", i, j) == 2) {
        if (strcmp(i, j) == 0) {
            printf("Same\n");
        } else {
            printf("Different\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how `%99s` tells `scanf()` to store at most 99 bytes into the destination arrays to avoid buffer overflows.

Also note how `scanf` return value must be tested to avoid accessing uninitialized data (it returns the number of successful conversions, which must be `2` for both `i` and `j` to contain valid C strings).

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the `*i` and `*j` with `i[50]` and `j[50]` respectively.

And here I avoided using `&i` as in case of a string (character array), the variable itself points to the first element of the array in question. Thus, there is no need to use the ‘&’ operator to pass the address.

And now this would work with `strcmp`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char i[50], j[50];
    printf("Enter strings: ");
    scanf("%s %s", i, j);
    if (strcmp(i, j) == 0) printf("Same \n");
    else printf("different\n");
 }
```

input:

*Enter strings:* `hello`(enter)

`hello`

output: `same`

Comment: The OP's `scanf("%s %s", &i, &j);` is incorrect regardless of whether `i` and `j` are arrays or pointers, but in the case of pointers it is *very* wrong.

Comment: *"I replaced the *i and *j with i[50] and j[50] respectively"* -------> What was wrong with OP's version? Why did you replace it? I think your answer would you be more complete if you added this information.